# ngClass funcion + expresion Angular2+

Tags: javascript, angular

estoy intentado combinar en un ngClass una expresion + una función sin embargo la expresión no se esta evaluando y no se ejecuta la clase, actualmente lo tengo así, es solo un ejemplo:

```
<div [ngClass]="[cargar(), {'hola':true}]"></div>

cargar() {
    return 'hola2';
  }
```

por lo que solo me esta aplicando la clase que trae cargar(), y hola no se esta aplicando aun sabiendo que la evaluo como verdad

aqui el ejemplo

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t35zo1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que veo en la documentación oficial de angular, en el atributo ngClass, solo se pueden colocar expresiones. puedes colocar string, arreglos u objetos. por tanto una función no es bien recibida.

No veo que permita combinar ambas maneras como lo haces, he intentado ejecutarlo y no lo permite, debes realizarlo de una u otra forma.

te dejo el link de la documentación oficial de angular https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Si lo que deseas es que se aplique una clase u otra según te parezca, una de las formas podría ser de la siguiente manera:

Tengo en mi css el las siguientes clases:

```js
export class AttrNgClass implements OnInit {

  public changeBackground: boolean;

  constructor() { }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.changeBackground = false;
   }

  public backGround(): void {
    this.changeBackground = !this.changeBackground;
  }

  backGround2() {
    return 'bg-dark-gray';
  }
}
```

```css
.text-blue {
    color: blue;
}

.bg-aqua {
    background-color: aqua !important;
}

.bg-dark-gray {
    background-color: darkgray;
}
```

```html
<div (click)="backGround()"
    [ngClass]="{'text-blue': true, 'bg-aqua': !changeBackground, 'bg-dark-gray': changeBackground}">
    Prueba de cambio de color
</div>

<div [ngClass]="[backGround2()]">
    otra prueba
</div>
```